# Jordan Normal Form and its conjugates

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Is it true that a matrix of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & x_1 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0   & x_2    & \ldots & 0 \\  
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & x_{n-1} \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
with nonzero $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ conjugate to the usual Jordan cell which has all $1$'s above the diagonal?

Comment: **Hint.** Assuming column vectors, and the implicit base is $v_{1}, \dots, v_{n}$, consider the new base given by $v_{n}' = v_{n}, v_{n-1}' = x_{n-1} v_{n-1}, \dots$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti  Thank you. I was thinking we can argue as follows. Every matrix is conjugate to a unique matrix in Jordan Normal form. Since the order of nilpotency of the above matrix is $n$ it cannot be conjugate to other matrices other than the usual Jordan cell with $1$'s above the diagonal.

Comment: @user49908: Your argument is correct.

Comment: @user49908, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. For an explicit similarity, note that the Jordan block is given by $J = DMD^{-1}$, where
$$
D = \pmatrix{1\\&x_1\\&&x_1x_2\\&&&\ddots\\ &&&&x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-2}x_{n-1}}, \\ M = 
\pmatrix{0 & x_1 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0   & x_2    & \ldots & 0 \\  
\vdots & \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & x_{n-1} \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0}.
$$